# "what did they try to do with this code?"

Tags: excel, vba

I found this hidden code in a common use form.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
If ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat <> 52 And ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat <> 50 Then
ActiveWorkbook.Application.VBE.CommandBars(1).FindControl(ID:=2578, recursive:=True).Execute
```

I do not know what use it has.

```
SendKeys "^{PGDN}"
SendKeys "%(C)" & "Cont_2015/*69"
SendKeys "%(o)" & "Cont_2015/*69"
SendKeys "{TAB}" & "~"
ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid GUID:="{0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", Major:=5, Minor:=3
```

that is all

```
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi DarkWes, you need to explain more what you've tried and what you're after with your question. Currently the three code blocks will not even compile. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code first unlocks the VB project and then runs some sendkeys macros - this work by simulating pressing keys on the keyboard, so this is running Control Pagedown, Alt C , "sometext", Alt o, "some text", Tab and finally Enter.

it then adds a reference to the project and finally saves and closes the file

It looks like a clumsy attempt to work around not having the correct reference set in the code.  I presume that the text, and the GUI have meaning in the context of the particular file

More details might be found [Here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-31887.html)